# MySQLDB import error in CGI python Script

Tags: python, cgi, cgi-bin

I write following script in cgi-bin while if I run this script from browser by entering URL then script gives an `500 internal server` error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb
import cgi
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Listing</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>listing</h2>"

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="password", db="DB_name")

cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from table")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print row[0]

print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

If I remove the DB connection lines then its working fine, but if I just add `import MySQLdb` then I get 500 internal server error.

Out put of

import sys

```
for p in sys.path: 
    print p + "<br/>"

/home/database/public_html/cgi-bin
/usr/lib64/python26.zip
/usr/lib64/python2.6
/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2
/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk
/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old
/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

Operating system is Redhat.

Comment: Have you tried to run the script from console and look at the error it's giving?

Comment: What does it say in the (presumably) Apache error log?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Its live server and I can not see Apache error log, any suggestions where I can see the log file ?

Comment: /var/log/apache2 or /var/log/httpd, depending on your distribution.

Comment: What? You're developing in your production environment? And you don't have enough information about it to know where the logs are?

Comment: Is there a way to check import MySQLdb related .so file ? OR can I include a static path to this .so file  ?

Comment: Its actually a development environment but I do not have access to server file system

Comment: You were able to resolve this issue? I am also facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like server problem. Contact your server support.